How to fetch Azure API Management's logs using C#?
I would like to use the logs from my Azure API Management and query for say number successfully called API, or how many API calls a user has made in the past month all within C#/dotnet.
I just need a way to access the data, but I am having trouble finding a way to achieve this since a lot of the current existing solutions seem to have been deprecated.
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.monitor.query import LogsQueryClient
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
from azure.core.exceptions import HttpResponseError
import pandas as pd
from datetime import timedelta
from azure.monitor.query import LogsQueryStatus
 
 
subscription_id = "..."
client_id = "..."
client_secret = "..."
tenant_id = "..."
 
credential = ClientSecretCredential(
      tenant_id=tenant_id,
      client_id=client_id,
      client_secret=client_secret
)
client = LogsQueryClient(credential)
 
query = "ApiManagementGatewayLogs ..."
 
 
try:
    response = client.query_workspace(os.environ["LOGS_WORKSPACE_ID"], query, timespan=timedelta(days=1))
    if response.status == LogsQueryStatus.PARTIAL:
        error = response.partial_error
        data = response.partial_data
        print(error)
    elif response.status == LogsQueryStatus.SUCCESS:
        data = response.tables
    for table in data:
        df = pd.DataFrame(data=table.rows, columns=table.columns)
        print(df)
except HttpResponseError as err:
    print("something fatal happened")
    print(err)

Above is my current code, I had moved to python instead of dotnet and the "LOGS_WORKSPACE_ID" I am not sure how to fix as I am simply trying to access Azure Portal's Monitor -> Logs and try to query.
The above code is based off of: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-monitor-query/azure.monitor.query.logsqueryclient?view=azure-python

Can you please share the code which you have tried

@IkhtesamAfrin I had just updated the post. Thanks!

Your question asks for C#, but your code is Python, do you want a solution in C# or Python?

@simon-pearson In python please, but I figured if there is a solution it probably wouldn't be too far off between the two. Thanks!

I am able to get the APIM logs using below code.
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.monitor.query import LogsQueryClient, LogsQueryStatus
from azure.core.exceptions import HttpResponseError
import pandas as pd
from datetime import timedelta
 
credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
client = LogsQueryClient(credential)
 
query = "ApiManagementGatewayLogs"
  
try:
    response = client.query_workspace("{LOGS_WORKSPACE_ID}", query, timespan=timedelta(days=1))
    if response.status == LogsQueryStatus.PARTIAL:
        error = response.partial_error
        data = response.partial_data
        print(error)
    elif response.status == LogsQueryStatus.SUCCESS:
        data = response.tables
    for table in data:
        df = pd.DataFrame(data=table.rows, columns=table.columns)
        pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
        print(df)
except HttpResponseError as err:
    print("something fatal happened")
    print(err)

Output-


If you are using os.environ["LOGS_WORKSPACE_ID"] to set the workspace id then execute set LOGS_WORKSPACE_ID="your_workspace_id" command to set the Id.


Thank you for the answer! Does this require the logs to be in the Logs Analytics Workspace? I do realize that it may just be easier to store logs there and use the above code. But I want to make sure that its not impossible to query the logs straight from Monitor

Yes, in this case the logs should be present in the log analytics workspace. By using this code, we are only fetching the logs from the log analytics

That makes sense thank you. And if I do choose to continue with this program and store the logs within analytics workspace, will I then be able to query to check which APIs are used by certain users? I am tasked to build a backend system to analyze costs and usages for my entire API Management so I have to ensure this is the best for the task. It is also to the best of my knowledge that most(not all) queries that are usable in the logs on the portal will be translatable to this function? Thanks :)

Yes, you can.
There is a REST API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/reports/list-by-user?view=rest-apimanagement-2022-08-01&tabs=HTTP too present to check the reports as per the users

@IkhtesamAfrin Gotcha thank you once again, you've been a great help!

Hi sorry to bother you again, I am having issues with DefaultAzureCredential as it keep using the wrong tenant under my account and displaying token not authenticated to view this resource, despite me changing tenant using az login --tenant . Would you happen to know why this is becoming an issue? Thank you in advance :)
